# List comprehension with a Boolean whose value changes throughout iterations

Tags: python, if-statement, list-comprehension, nested-loops

I'm attempting to create a list comprehension from a nested for loop with if statements, and I can't figure it out. I scanned the internet for hours but couldn't find a solution.

The loop looks like that:

```
lengths = []
data_frame = p.read_excel(fasta_path_[:-2] + 'xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
seqids = data_frame['qseqid'].tolist()
identical_ids = None

with open(fasta_path_, 'r') as fasta_file:
    for line in fasta_file.readlines():
        if identical_ids is True:
            lengths.append(len(line.strip()))
        for seq_id in seqids:
            if seq_id in line:
                identical_ids = True
                continue
            else:
                identical_ids = False
                continue
```

My last attempt:

```
lengths = [len(line.strip()) for line in fasta_file.readlines() if identical_ids for seq_id in seqids if seq_id in line identical_ids := True else identical_ids := False]
```

**Edit**

After running and fixing the code many times, it looks like the final result can't be written as a list comprehension:

```
seqids = p.read_csv(csv_path, usecols=['qseqid'])
seqids = seqids['qseqid'].tolist()
queries_lengths = []
count = 0
id_in_tag_line = None
with open(fasta_path_, 'r') as fasta_file:
    for line in fasta_file.readlines():
        if count < len(seqids) and seqids[count] in line:
            id_in_tag_line = True
            count += 1
            continue
        if id_in_tag_line:
            queries_lengths.append(len(line))
            id_in_tag_line = None
```

Since the two lists that are used in this code are very big, the for loop runs about 30,000, so instead of using a nested for loop I used a counter.

If anyone thinks there's a way (or a need) to write it as a list comprehension, I'd love to hear new ideas.

Comment: A list comprehension is about creating a list with some values; your second loop has nothing to do with including values in a list.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Does that list comprehension make the code easier to read, or harder?

Comment: May be you will be able to do this using `walrus` operator but for me the first solution is much more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a far more simplified version of your code that does the same thing:

```
identical_ids = None

with open(fasta_path_, 'r') as fasta_file:
    for line in fasta_file:
        if identical_ids:
            lengths.append(len(line.strip()))
        identical_ids = seqids[-1] in line
```

It should be easier to work with.

Here is the list comprehension:

```
with open(fasta_path_, 'r') as fasta_file:
    lengths = [len(line.strip()) for i, line in enumerate(fasta_file) if seqids[-1] in line and i]
```

Explanation for the `sedis[-1]`:

You have

```
        for seq_id in seqids:
            if seq_id in line:
                identical_ids = True
                continue
            else:
                identical_ids = False
                continue
```

Where you are basically iterating through the `seqids` array, and setting `identical_ids` to whether each element is in `line`.

It iterates all the way till the last element of `seqids`, and `identical_ids` will be set to whether that last element is in `line`, making the previous iterations null.

Answer (score 1):

The interpretation what this code is doing, or trying to do, comes down to this clause:

```
for seq_id in seqids:
    if seq_id in line:
        identical_ids = True
        continue
    else:
        identical_ids = False
        continue
```

As @AnnZen notes in her answer, this is effectively doing:

```
identical_ids = seqids[-1] in line
```

But this renders the code questionable in its approach, as well as in its use of two `continue` no-ops.  Assuming the code is slightly broken, it might have intended to read:

```
for seq_id in seqids:
    if seq_id in line:
        identical_ids = True
        break
    else:
        identical_ids = False
        continue
```

That is, ***any*** element of `seqid` is found in `line`.  Or it might have been intended to read:

```
for seq_id in seqids:
    if seq_id in line:
        identical_ids = True
        continue
    else:
        identical_ids = False
        break
```

That is, ***all*** elements of `seqids` are contained in `line`.  Both interpretations still including one `continue` no-op.  Regardless, it seems unreasonable to reduce this to a list comprehension until the intended function is clarified by the OP.

Comment: Cool, 2500 answers!

Comment: *"it seems unreasonable to reduce this to a list comprehension until the intended function is clarified by the OP"* Stated by th OP: *"I'm attempting to create a list comprehension"*

Comment: @AnnZen, *list comprehension* is the *form*, not the *function*.  And I don't have a clue what your other comment means.

Comment: What do you mean *"not the function"*? What about the OP's attempt: `lengths = [len(line.strip()) for line in fasta_file.readlines() if identical_ids for seq_id in seqids if seq_id in line identical_ids := True else identical_ids := False]` The other comment means [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKg6F.png)